# Django website not working as expected on home url, but eventually works upon consistent retry

Tags: django, nginx, single-page-application

so I have this single page application that runs django backend [here](https://www.pythonyard.com). It actually has 4 header option: **Jobs (the default), competitions, learn, about**. When you visit the application, sometimes it fails to load the jobs section. The spinner just keeps spinning, and when you check the console, you will see an error that says `VM96:2 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!doctype "... is not valid JSON`

Now this is very confusing to me because if you keep clicking the Jobs link, it will eventually load the jobs page correctly (or you can keep trying a complete reload of the url, it will eventually load properly). However, the other hyperlinks work. This problem only happens on the job page, which is the homepage

**nginx configuration**

```
server {
   server_name pythonyard.com www.pythonyard.com *.pythonyard.com;

   location /static/ {
      alias /home/kenechukwu_webapp/allpython/backend/static/;
   }

   location / {
     try_files $uri @node;
   }

   location @node {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
   }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/pythonyard.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/pythonyard.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
server {
    if ($host = www.pythonyard.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = pythonyard.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


   listen 80;
   server_name pythonyard.com www.pythonyard.com *.pythonyard.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
```

**settings.py**

```
"""
Django settings for backend project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.2.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/
"""
import os
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = ''

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', '127.0.0.1', '0.0.0.0', '34.171.199.103']

CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS=['https://*.pythonyard.com']

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from rest_framework import routers
from appv1 import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


router = routers.DefaultRouter()

urlpatterns = [
    # path('', include(router.urls)),
    # path('', views.JobView.as_view()),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls), # my admin page
    path('', views.index),
    # path('url_checker', views.check_url),
    # path('', views.FrontendAppView.as_view()),

    path('about/', views.AboutView.as_view()),
    path('learn/', views.LearnView.as_view()),

    path('viewprojects/', views.ProjectView.as_view()), # view list of projects
    path('projectdetails/<project_id>/', views.ProjectDetailsView.as_view()), # view detail of projects
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta name="description" content="Python Jobs, Competitions, and Learnings" />
      <title>Python Yard</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/style.css">
      <link rel="icon" href="./static/images/favicon.png">
   </head>
   <body class="min-h-screen bg-gray-50">
      <div class="max-w-screen-xl mx-auto">
         <div class="relative">
            <div class="flex justify-between items-center px-4 py-6 sm:px-6 md:justify-start md:space-x-10">
               <div>
                  <a href="/" class="flex">
                  <img class="h-8 w-auto sm:h-10" src="./static/images/logo.png"
                     alt="PythonYard">
                  </a>
               </div>
               <div class="flex-1 flex items-center justify-between space-x-12">
                  <nav class="hidden sm:flex space-x-10">
                     <a href="/"
                        class="text-base leading-6 font-medium text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:text-gray-900 transition ease-in-out duration-150">
                        Jobs
                     </a>
                     <a href="/competitions"
                        class="text-base leading-6 font-medium text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-900  focus:outline-none focus:text-gray-900 transition ease-in-out duration-150">
                        Competitions
                     </a>
                     <a href="/learn"
                        class="text-base leading-6 font-medium text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-900  focus:outline-none focus:text-gray-900 transition ease-in-out duration-150">
                        Learn
                     </a>
                     <a href="/about"
                        class="text-base leading-6 font-medium text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:text-gray-900 transition ease-in-out duration-150">
```

my index.js

```
    const routes = {
        404: {
            template: "/templates/404.html",
            title: "404",
            description: "Page not found",
        },
        "/": {
            method: JobHandler,
            template: "/templates/index.html",
            title: "Home",
            description: "This is the home page",
        },
        "/competitions": {
            method: CompetitionHandler,
            template: "/templates/about.html",
            title: "About Us",
            description: "This is the about page",
        },
        "/learn": {
            method: LearnHandler,
            template: "/templates/about.html",
            title: "About Us",
            description: "This is the about page",
        },
        "/about": {
            method: AboutHandler,
            template: "/templates/about.html",
            title: "About Us",
            description: "This is the about page",
        },
    };

    const route = (event) => {
        event = event || window.event; // get window.event if event argument not provided
        event.preventDefault();
        // window.history.pushState(state, unused, target link);
        window.history.pushState({}, "", event.target.href);
        locationHandler();
    };

    const locationHandler = async () => {
        const location = window.location.pathname; // get the url path
        // if the path length is 0, set it to primary page route
        if (location.length == 0) {
            location = "/";
        }
        const url_route = routes[location] || routes["404"];
        (url_route["method"])();
        document.title = url_route.title;
        // set the description of the document to the description of the route
        document
            .querySelector('meta[name="description"]')
            .setAttribute("content", url_route.description);
    };

    // add an event listener to the window that watches for url changes
    window.onpopstate = locationHandler;
    // call the urlLocationHandler function to handle the initial url
    window.route = route;

    locationHandler(); # to load the initial request of the jobs
```

I have tried to play around with the proxy pass but nothing seems to be working.

My expectation is for the homepage url (/) to work as other work, which is to load the page, and immediately call the `locationHandler` method to populate the jobs content, and further clicks to other urls will populate their own content, and if the user then clicks on the jobs link, it should populate the job content again.

Edit: my error log

```
2023/08/03 00:09:29 [debug] 675473#675473: accept on 0.0.0.0:80, ready: 0
2023/08/03 00:09:29 [debug] 675473#675473: posix_memalign: 000055A4636A8C10:512 @16
2023/08/03 00:09:29 [debug] 675473#675473: *165 accept: 189.127.145.166:45475 fd:5
2023/08/03 00:09:29 [debug] 675473#675473: *165 event timer add: 5: 60000:6416160881
2023/08/03 00:09:29 [debug] 675473#675473: *165 reusable connection: 1
2023/08/03 00:09:29 [debug] 675473#675473: *165 epoll add event: fd:5 op:1 ev:80002001
2023/08/03 00:09:29 [debug] 675473#675473: *165 http wait request handler
2023/08/03 00:09:29 [debug] 675473#675473: *165 malloc: 000055A4636261B0:1024
2023/08/03 00:09:29 [debug] 675473#675473: *165 recv: eof:0, avail:-1
2023/08/03 00:09:29 [debug] 675473#675473: *165 recv: fd:5 186 of 1024
2023/08/03 00:09:29 [debug] 675473#675473: *165 reusable connection: 0
2023/08/03 00:09:29 [debug] 675473#675473: *165 posix_memalign: 000055A463700410:4096 @16
2023/08/03 00:09:29 [debug] 675473#675473: *165 http process request line
2023/08/03 00:09:29 [debug] 675473#675473: *165 http request line: "GET / HTTP/1.1"
2023/08/03 00:09:29 [debug] 675473#675473: *165 http uri: "/"
2023/08/03 00:09:29 [debug] 675473#675473: *165 http args: ""
2023/08/03 00:09:29 [debug] 675473#675473: *165 http exten: ""
2023/08/03 00:09:29 [debug] 675473#675473: *165 posix_memalign: 000055A463646420:4096 @16
2023/08/03 00:09:29 [debug] 675473#675473: *165 http process request header line
2023/08/03 00:09:29 [debug] 675473#675473: *165 http header: "Host: 34.171.199.103:80"
2023/08/03 00:09:29 [debug] 675473#675473: *165 http header: "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"
2023/08/03 00:09:29 [debug] 675473#675473: *165 http header: "Content-Length: 0"
2023/08/03 00:09:29 [debug] 675473#675473: *165 http header done
2023/08/03 00:09:29 [debug] 675473#675473: *165 event timer del: 5: 6416160881
2023/08/03 00:09:29 [debug] 675473#675473: *165 generic phase: 0
2023/08/03 00:09:29 [debug] 675473#675473: *165 rewrite phase: 1
2023/08/03 00:09:29 [debug] 675473#675473: *165 test location: "/"
2023/08/03 00:09:29 [debug] 675473#675473: *165 using configuration "/"
2023/08/03 00:09:29 [debug] 675473#675473: *165 http cl:0 max:1048576
2023/08/03 00:09:29 [debug] 675473#675473: *165 rewrite phase: 3
2023/08/03 00:09:29 [debug] 675473#675473: *165 post rewrite phase: 4
2023/08/03 00:09:29 [debug] 675473#675473: *165 generic phase: 5
2023/08/03 00:09:29 [debug] 675473#675473: *165 generic phase: 6
2023/08/03 00:09:29 [debug] 675473#675473: *165 generic phase: 7
2023/08/03 00:09:29 [debug] 675473#675473: *165 access phase: 8
2023/08/03 00:09:29 [debug] 675473#675473: *165 access phase: 9
2023/08/03 00:09:29 [debug] 675473#675473: *165 access phase: 10
2023/08/03 00:09:29 [debug] 675473#675473: *165 post access phase: 11
2023/08/03 00:09:29 [debug] 675473#675473: *165 generic phase: 12
2023/08/03 00:09:29 [debug] 675473#675473: *165 try files handler
2023/08/03 00:09:29 [debug] 675473#675473: *165 http script var: "/"
2023/08/03 00:09:29 [debug] 675473#675473: *165 trying to use file: "/" "/var/www/html/"
2023/08/03 00:09:29 [debug] 675473#675473: *165 http script var: "/"
```

Comment: The error you are getting is a bit of a red herring. The server error 500 page is being delivered as HTML, not the JSON your function expects and that is where the `<doctype...` comes from. To properly debug you may want to turn on DEBUG = TRUE in your settings to get the actual error message

Comment: YOu've also got 2 `const route =` declarations that may be confusing things

Comment: But I suspect these might be side issues because I get the same random server error 500 pages visiting `/viewjobs/` 4 out of 5 times.  You may need to consult your server error logs

Comment: Thank you, I have changed the second route, but I am still getting the issue. I will edit the question to add the log file, and update the route